# User profile needs merging

Tags: support, status-completed

I'm not quite sure how this happened, but it appears I have two logins that are the same: ME!

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3136/ionline247 <-- Google ID Login

and

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4072/ionline247

I'd love for these profiles to be merged.  Also is there a way to make a certain profile the master login?  I've been using my Google ID to login for a while and I'm not sure how this became an issue.

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing! I've merged your profiles so that the Google ID one is the master.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3136/ionline247

Comment: Excellent! Now I can use the site more often. :)